# JHtmlArea Set html

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, jhtmlarea

I have  been using the [jhtmlarea](http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/) for a wysiwyg editor.  Most of it is working.  Though I can't figure out how to set the html inside of the textarea.
I have tried .html, .val, .attr('value',''), .text, though none of them work.

Any suggestions on how to do this/a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

$("#yourTextArea").htmlarea('pasteHTML', "HTML to paste");

Hope it helps you and someone else :)

Comment: Ended up using bbcode, but thanks a lot for this, will help in future projects

Comment: You can also do this:

$("#jhtm").contents().find('body').html(data);

If you change the JHtml script:
- find line 41 (on the minified version) or search for "<iframe " string, and then replace that line with
var iframe=this.iframe=$("<iframe id=\"jhtm\" />").height(textarea.height());

This will give you an ID to you iFrame object. Although it will only work with 1 iFrame but you can manage a workaround for sure! :)

Answer (score 8):

Set the original text area value and call `updateHtmlArea`:

```
$('#textAreaID').val(newHtml).htmlarea('updateHtmlArea');
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, this should've been the accepted answer.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is what you're after but if you mean setting the text inside the jHtmlArea iFrame then you'll need to use the `pasteHTML("text to insert");` method.

E.g.

$("#myTextAreaId").htmlarea
    ({ this.pasteHTML("Here's some programtically entered text."); })

Comment: Almost there - inside the 'function click() { }' part you can simply start using the this keyword. i.e. this.pasteHTML("Here's some programtically entered text.");  There's no need to re-fetch the element using jQuery ($("#myTextAreaId").htmlarea).

Comment: This is what I have, tested in chrome, and Firefox, it doesn't work.  Can you show me what I'm doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/aYYJe/3/

Comment: The script won't save on the site? Not my fault! sorry